# Localization of Watch Extension is missing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit

I have made an iOS 13 app with a watch extension. The app is written in English. I have localized it to German. Everything is fine with the iPhone app; however the watch extension is only available in English. **The German localization is not loaded.**

When I list the available localizations by printing<sup>1</sup> like so:

```
print(Bundle.main.localizations)
```

the **iPhone app** gives me:

```
["en", "Base", "de"]
```

which is fine for me,
but the **Watch Extension** only lists:

```
["en"]
```

which isn't correct – **"de" is missing**.

---

I have added German as a localization in the Interface Builder ([Interface Builder Languages Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBHn3.png)) but that doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried removing the German localization completely from the project and adding it back – didn't work either. ([Localization screenshot with German localization enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHOu.png))

---

**What am I missing?**

---

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

<sup>1</sup> I know that printing to the console is obsolete, you should use oslog instead, but I haven't gotten around to that yet, to be honest.

Comment: By the way, I am testing both in the simulator and on a (German) Apple Watch. It's the same with both.

Comment: I have also added a third localization, French, and found the same problem.